# Create channel in GCM(android)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push

Sorry for my english. I few days try to understand how create own channel in google cloud message. For example i subscribe like this:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    String token = instanceID.getToken(PROJECT_NUMBER,
                            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                    GcmPubSub.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).subscribe(token, "/topics/users", null);
```

i get token from server and then i subscribe to this token in `/topics/users`. How i can subscribe channel like this `p123123` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To subscribe to a topic, the client app calls GCM PubSub `subscribe()` with the GCM registration token and topic name. You need to [obtain a registration token](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) and subscribe to the topic using that token.

```
private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
    GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
    for (String topic : TOPICS) {
        pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
    }
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging).